# Python equivalent to Matlab bootci function

Tags: python, matlab

I want to calculate the confidence interval of a Markov Chain. I have an MC transition matrix. I know Matlab `bootci` function can be used for this.

Is there a Python equivalent to Matlab `bootci` function

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://scikits.appspot.com/bootstrap.

```
import bootstrap as boot
```

and then call `boot.ci`